# ловлю такую ошибку Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs

когда  запускаю код ловлю вышеуказанную ошибку в компоненте Login.jsx

Вот мой файл Login.jsx

```
export default function  Login () {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(1);

  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
  const { email,  password } = state;

  const handleChangge = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
}

    return (
      <div className=" justify-center align-middle ">
      <Box sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
                       <h1 style={{display:'flex', justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center',margin:'10px 0',fontSize:'25px' }}>Авторизация</h1>
        <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: 'divider' ,margin:'10px 0',display:'flex',justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
          <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChangge} aria-label="basic tabs example">
            
            <Tab label="Войти " {...a11yProps(0)} />
            <Tab label="Зарегистрироваться" {...a11yProps(1)} />
            
          </Tabs>
        </Box>
        <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        <Box
        component="form"
        sx={{
          '& > :not(style)': {  width: '25ch', },
        }}
        noValidate
        autoComplete="off"
        >
          <h1
          className='flex justify-center align-middle font-semibold fz-20px'
          >Войти</h1>
    <div className="w- mb-10" >
    <InputText
    value={email}
    label="Введите email"
    type="email"
    onChange={handleChangge('email')}
    validators={[
      {check: validateEmail.email, message:'Неккоректный Email' },
      {check: required.required, message:'Это поле обьязательное' }
      ]}
    
    />
    <InputPassword
    value={password}
    type='password'
    label={'Введите пароль'}
    onChange={handleChangge('password')}
    validators={[
     {check: validateNumber.required, message:'Это поле обьязательное' }
     ]}
    />
    
  <p style={{ marginTop:"5px"}}>Забыли пароль?</p>
  
    <Button variant="contained"
     sx={{
      margin:"20px 0 ",
      width: "100%",
      textAlign: "center",
      background: "#000000"
    }}
    >Войти</Button>
  
  <p className='justify-center align-middle'
          > Войти с помощью :</p>
      <div  className='flex justify-center' >
    <div style={{width:"100px", margin:"10px 35px 0 20px", cursor:"pointer",borderRadius:"10px", }}> 
     <FaVk size={"50px"}
     className=' hover:bg-blue-50/90 focus:bg-rose-50/90 active:bg-rose-50'
     />
    </div>
    <div style={{width:"100px", margin:"10px 20px 0 35px", cursor:"pointer",borderRadius:"10px", }}>
     <AiFillFacebook 
     className=' hover:bg-blue-50/90 focus:bg-rose-50/90 active:bg-rose-50'
     size={"50px"}/>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </Box> 
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
     <Register/>
        </TabPanel>
      </Box>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас идёт по кругу вызов обработчика > смена значения > вызов обработчика
Потому что функция не присваивается в onChange инпута, а вызывается

Замените везде

```
onChange={handleChangge('email')}
```

на

```
onChange={(e) => handleChangge(e, 'email')}
```

**Upd**

```
function handleChange(e, fieldName) {
  setValues(({
     [fieldName]: e.target.value 
  }))
}
```

**One more UPD**
Не совсем понимаю, зачем вам setValue если у вас есть стэйт
В данном случае было бы правильнее

```
function handleChange(e, fieldName) {
  setState(prev => ({ 
     ...prev, 
     [fieldName]: e.target.value 
  }))
}
```

Comment: И кстати, ```handleChange``` было бы правильнее, а не ```handleChangge```

Comment: Кажется понял. Вы пытаетесь повесить 1 обработчик и на смену табов, и на значения в форме. Лучше отделите логику табов и обработчик от значений в форме ```const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState('registration')```